# Doc2Vec for dataset with several text fields: concatenate or separate models?

Tags: classification, text-mining, word2vec, gensim

I have a dataset with several fields: `description, name, header`. I want to train doc2vec out of it, so that I could use vectors for classification.

So I wonder, should I concatenate all the fields together into a single document for each sample or should I train separate model for each field?. Some fields may be missing (e.g. there may be no `description`).

If I train as a single document, should I emphasize context of each filed (e.g. `'NameStart'+ sampleName + 'NameEnd' + 'HeaderStart' + sampleHeader + 'HeaderEnd'`...) or just concatenate everything together?

I was inclined to train separate vectors for each field, but if some fields are missing for some samples, there'll be no representation for them, am I right?

Comment: I think that really depends on your data and task. It is usually recommended to start from basic models, so I'd train on the context and see how my classifier performs first.